# Specify RequireJS "data-main" attribute in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, requirejs, web-deployment-project

I am creating a JSF web application and I am trying to use RequireJS to structure my JavaScript files.

However, I cannot get it to work, as RequireJS requires a `"data-main"` attribute to be placed in the HTML `script` tag and `outputScript` does not support that.

I have tried to set it up without the `"data-main"` attribute and failed.

My directory tree looks like this:

```
- webapp
  - resources
    + css
    - js
      - app
          signup.js
      - lib
          jquery.js
          require.js
        common-spec.js
        signup-spec.js
  signup.xhtml
```

I have put the following in the `head` section of the JSF page:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript name="js/lib/require.js" />
    <h:outputScript>
        require.config({
            baseUrl: "js/lib",
            paths: {
                app: '../app'
            }
        });
        require(["signup-spec"]);
    </h:outputScript>
</h:head>
```

The result is that "signup-spec.js" cannot be found, I suppose because the `baseUrl` is set to another directory (it looks for it into `resources/js/lib`).

Basically, `signup-spec` is what I would put in the `"data-main"` attribute. I really don't know what to do. Working without `"data-main"` really confuses me.

Has anyone have any suggestion? Thanks ahead!

Comment: Check this `pass-through` library http://jsfcorner.blogspot.com/2013/06/jsf-22-pass-through-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

you don't **have to** use a data-main, you can if you desire. If not specified just load your config after it :

```
    <utils:outputScript name="require.js"/>
    <utils:outputScript name="requireConfig.js"/>
```